# How To Make An Application Icon Progress Indicator In Java?

Tags: java, windows

I have some Java code which uploads a file to the internet. I'd like it to be able to show a progress bar over top of its icon in the Windows taskbar. Like this:

[image: Progress active]

[image: Progress suspended]

Is there a way to do this in Java?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Taskbar.html) may help, but I am not really sure...

Comment: Yep! That helped, thank you!